# How to use Visual Studio's Intellisense with complex JS files

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

Here is my scenario, simply put.

JS File 1 (Namespace.js):

```
/// <reference path="Namespace.more.js" />
var Namespace = {
    property1 = 'something useful';
}
```

JS File 2 (Namespace.more.js):

```
Namespace.more = {
    another = 'another useful thing';
}
```

This is much more complex in the actual implementation, but for my purpose it'll serve fine. I cannot get the intellisense to work correctly on the original file. It makes sense, it complains the the Namespace object does not exist (which it doesn't at the start of the file).

My question is, how would you properly organize these documents, and get the correct intellisense? Assuming there is much more than just the simple object described here.

I have many files which build on a single file that has the original namespace delcaration, each new object has its own file.

Comment: That's invalid syntax; you need `:`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<reference>` is backwards.

You need to reference the original file (which creates the namespace) in `.more` (which uses it).

Comment: Okay. I understand this, but what happens if I have a second .more (say .somemore ). If I reference the files this way then I wouldn't be able to see the Namespace.somemore from the .more file, does that make sense?

Comment: @elweb: You need to add two `<reference>`s

Comment: It seems no matter what I do I can't get it to give me intellisense for items created further up the line. I can get .more to show within itself, but anything that builds on the .more won't work.    Same applies to the original namespace, I can get things to show that were created within itself, but if they build on it, it won't show me the intellisense.

Comment: You need to `<reference>` `.more` from the files that use it.

Comment: I do that now and it doesn't work. Just like in my original example, it seems since the reference is dependent upon the file I am currently using, it can't give me any intellisense.